# when the resistor is high, is the output voltage low or high?

Tags: resistors, multimeter

I am investigating potential/voltage divider circuits. I have read alot about voltage and resistance but am confused on one thing. When the resistor being tested by the voltmeter is high ohms is the output voltage low or high?

Comment: What is "output voltage" in this context? Output from what? You have only mentioned a resistor, which doesn't really have any input or output.

Comment: Equations governing resistive voltage divider can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#Resistive_divider) and [here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_6/1.html).

Answer (score 5):

It means nothing about the voltage, only that the resistor is of a high value. When testing resistance with a multimeter, you should have no power applied to the circuit, this will interfere with the readings. If you currently have power applied, then ignore the reading and test with power off.

The multimeter applies it's own power to test the resistance.

To test the voltage, you do apply power to the circuit.

You seem to be a little confused about [Ohm's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) (and possibly multimeters) If you can show us your divider and exactly how you are testing it (where probes are placed, setting of multimeter) then a more specific answer can be given.

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer this question, let's make clear how I interpret it: we are measuring the resistance \$R\$ of a resistor with a multimeter. You know the multimeter applies a constant current \$I\$ to the resistor and measures the voltage \$V\$ over the resistor. Now you want to know whether this voltage is high or low if the resistance is high or low.

Given [Ohm's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), \$V = I\cdot{}R\$, in which we can make \$I\$ a constant: \$V = c\cdot{}R\$. Now you can easily see that there is a linear relation between \$R\$ and \$V\$, so a higher resistance \$R\$ will result in a higher output voltage of the multimeter \$V\$.

Comment: Ohm meters don't generally apply a constant current.  Often it's a voltage divider with a known and accurate upper leg.  By the way, I didn't do the downvote.  That was here before I wrote this comment.

Comment: What you say might be true and is a good note. I just know my multimeter works like this and I found it here: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_does_a_multimeter_measure_resistance